# awk split function with regular expression

Tags: awk, split, solaris

I have to split  line on two criterias, i did it with awk and its split function.

Following is sample input

```
|ERROR|ErrorHandler|[opName:Fulfill][msisdn:123][clientTrxId:[eventId:1][actionId:34]]|Failed delivery
```

Below i used to parse it

```
grep ErrorHandler a.log | awk -F'|' '{split($3,a,"\[(.*?)\]"); print a[1]}'
```

I am expecting output like
    [opName:Fulfill]
but it's showing whole line

```
[opName:Fulfill][msisdn:123][clientTrxId:[eventId:1][actionId:34]]
```

its due to last ]].

How i can modify my regular expression so it parse like below

```
[opName:Fulfill]
[msisdn:123]
[clientTrxId:[eventId:1][actionId:34]]
```

Comment: You cannot handle matched-pairs like that with a normal regular expression.

Comment: any alternate suggestion to achieve this task

Answer (score 4):

You never need grep with awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. I don't know how you'd do this with a regexp, I'd just count square brackets:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
/ErrorHandler/ {
    # identify the fields by analyzing one char at a time
    for (charNr=1;charNr<=length($4);charNr++) {
        char = substr($4,charNr,1)
        if ( (char == "[") && (++braceCnt == 1) ) {
            fld = ""
        }
        fld = fld char
        if ( (char == "]") && (--braceCnt == 0) ) {
            flds[++numFlds] = fld
        }
    }

    # print the fields
    for (fldNr=1;fldNr<=numFlds;fldNr++) {
        print flds[fldNr]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk a.log
[opName:Fulfill]
[msisdn:123]
[clientTrxId:[eventId:1][actionId:34]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use `awk` along with an output field separator to handle the carriage returns:

```
grep ErrorHandler a.log | awk -F'[|\\]]+' 'BEGIN {OFS="]\n"} {print $4, $5, $6 "]" $7 "]]"}'
```

*I haven't tested this, although it might give you some idea for an alternative to split.

Answer (score 0):

[lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) can do matched-pair matching.

```
printf '|ERROR|ErrorHandler|[opName:Fulfill][msisdn:123][clientTrxId:[eventId:1][actionId:34]]|Failed delivery\n' | \
    awk -F \| '{print $4}' | \
    lua -e 'for line in io.lines() do
        for w in line:gmatch("%b[]") do
            print(w)
        end
    end'
```